# Return specific value in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I need to write a function in MATLAB that, given the birth dates of two people in the form `( y1,m1,d1,y2,m2,d2 )` (year, month, day) will compare them and return 1 if the first person is older, -1 if the first person is younger and 0 if they have the same age. I have done the following:

```
function classify( y1,m1,d1,y2,m2,d2 )
if y1 > y2
    return -1;
elseif y1 < y2
    return 1;
elseif y1 == y2
    if m1 > m2
        return -1;
    elseif m1 < m2
        return 1;
    elseif m1 == m2
        if d1 > d2
            return -1;
        elseif d1 < d2
            return 1;
        elseif d1 == d2
            return 0;
        end
    end
end
end
```

But it gives error. How do you return a value in MATLAB without having to declare a variable? I just need to return the 1,0,-1 depending on the result, and it seems that `return 1;` does not work well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have a function return a value, you need to declare the corresponding variables in the function definition line. The `return` function simply exits the function prematurely, it does not return values all by itself.

```
function output = functionName()
    %# assign output
    output = 1;
end
```

Similarly to how you can input multiple values, you can have it return multiple values

```
function [add, mult] = addAndMultiply(a,b)

    add = a+b;
    mult = a*b;

end
```

Call it as

```
[u,v] = addAndMultiply(1,2);
```

Now, to your specific problem to compare two dates: I strongly recommend using `datenum`:

```
function firstIsOlder = classify( y1,m1,d1,y2,m2,d2 )

    firstDate  = datenum(y1, m1, d1);
    secondDate = datenum(y2, m2, d2);

    %# if first is older, sign is +1, if both equal, sign is 0
    firstIsOlder = sign(secondDate - firstDate);
```

Answer (score 2):

In Matlab, `return` [is used](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/return.html) to return control to invoking function rather than to return a value. To get a value out of a function, you should do something like this:

```
function result = classify(a, b)
if a > b
   result = 1;
elseif a < b
   result = -1;
else
   result = 0;
end
```

`return` is useful when you want to interrupt your function. However, similar to `goto`, it may make your code less readable and therefore prone to errors.

By the way, what you are trying to do could be done shorter by comparing two dates:

```
function result = classify(y1, m2, d1, y2, m2, d2)
date1 = datenum(y1, m1, d1);
date2 = datenum(y2, m2, d2);

if date1 < date2
    result = 1;
elseif date1 > date2
    result = -1;
else
    result = 0;
end
```

You can make it still shorter by avoiding the if-clause:

```
result = sign(date2 - date1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Matlab functions look like this:

```
function older = classify(y1, m1, d1, y2, m2, d2)
    ...
end
```

The `older` variable is your return variable - the last assignment inside the function gets returned.

Comment: Ah, yes, I know about that! I just thought I could do it as well without returning a variable, but just a number (in a boolean kind of sense). Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

firstly [classify](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/stats/classify.html?refresh=true) is built in function in MATLAB it isn't a good idea to make your own function with the same name.

- you haven't defined an output in the function definition so just add `[A] =` before the word function
- [return](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/return.html?searchHighlight=return) doesn't return a value but returns control to the function that invoked it.. so it isn't usable in your situation.. replace the returns with `A =` you will also need to declare and define A before your `if` statements start.

PS. i have used `A` as an example but you can use any name for a [variable](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isvarname.html) as long as it starts with a letter and less than 63 characters long.

```
function [A] = classi( y1,m1,d1,y2,m2,d2 )

A = 0;

if y1 > y2
    A =  -1;
elseif y1 < y2
    A =  1;
elseif y1 == y2
    if m1 > m2
 ...
```